# custom post type dynamically shows in menubar in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I am developing a hospital website in wordpress. For that I make a custom post type "Services". All the hospital services (ex:ICU, CCU, NICU, Emergency etc) are going under this "Services".
So now I want to show this custom post type "Serviecs" in the menubar and also want to show those services (ex:ICU, CCU, NICU, Emergency etc) under the "Services" as a dropdown menu dynamically. While a new

How to do that? Anybody help please?

[image]

[image]